# Django URL pattern (~~/?item_id=2)

Tags: django, url

https://xxxx/category_check_view/?item_id=2

Above is a sample of URL pattern. How should i configured my URL in order to enable it to redirect to the right view? 
I seem to get it working for a url like this https://xxxx/category_check_view/2/ only so far.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a view either in the url:

```
/category_check_view/2
```

Or via `GET` params:

```
/category_check_view/?item_id=2
```

`GET` params are not processed by the URL handler, but rather passed directly to the `GET` param dict accessible in a view at `request.GET`.

The Django (i.e. preferred) way to do handle URLs is the first one. So you would have a URL conf:

```
(r'^category_check_view/(\d{4})$', 'proj.app.your_view'),
```

And a matching view:

```
def your_view(request, id):
    obj = Obj.objects.get(id=id)
    # ...
```

However, if you insist on passing the param via `GET` you would just do:

```
(r'^category_check_view$', 'proj.app.your_view'),
```

And:

```
def your_view(request):
    id = request.GET.get('item_id')
    obj = Obj.objects.get(id=id)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use get parameters in URL pattern. Use them in your view:

```
item_id = request.GET.get('item_id')
```